# add item to array(Hooks) react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-state

I watch course about react js
and And in it Adds a new item to the array(hook) as follows:

```
useState([new item , old Array]);
```

But I repeat this, the array turns into an object

Whatever I searched for, I saw the following result:

```
useState([ old array ,new item ]);
```

But the method worked well in the course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add items to an array using React hooks you need to use the spread operator to get the old array and then add the new item.

`setState([...oldArray, newItem])`

Comment: @Morteza.s17 make sure you use the setState function and not useState when updating it which is what you have in your question

Answer (score 2):

You should use the spread operator: setState(prev => [...prev, newItem]);

Answer (score 1):

A better way of updating an array using react-hooks is to pass in a callback function to the hook, like this:

```js
setState((oldState) => [...oldState, newItem])
```

This is considered a best practice and is a lot more performant than directly spreading the old state.